# Android ViewPager with center item bigger

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I want to create a ViewPager with
- The selected center item being bigger than others
- Portion of Previous & Next items being always visible.
I am using `viewPager.setPageMargin(-20);` to make portion of Previous & Next items visible. But, how to make selected center item little bit bigger than other items.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can set the Layout parameters to be x% bigger in the onPageSelected() method.

```
     ViewPager pager ;

    int prevIndex = 0;

    int oldWidth, oldHeight, 

//initialize these to be bigger than the old ones

newWidth, newHeight;
    pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        public void onPageSelected(int index) {

// Set the layout params of the newly selected page to be the large width and height

            View v = pager.getChildAt(index);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    newWidth, newHeight);

            v.setLayoutParams(params);

// Don't forget to set the past view to the old layout params.

            View oldV = pager.getChildAt(prevIndex);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams oldParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    oldWidth, oldHeight);

            oldV.setLayoutParams(oldParams);

            prevIndex = index;
        }

        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Comment: You're very welcome :) I hope that helps!
let me know if it doesn't, maybe there's another way around it.

Comment: Hey all, I'm trying to something similar. My Viepager items are fragments containing an imageview. I can't seem to grab the items view to change the layout size.