# ViewPager with multiple visible children and selected bigger

Tags: android, android-viewpager

In my `Activity` I've added a `Gallery`-like `View` using Dave Smith's [`PagerContainer`](https://gist.github.com/devunwired/8cbe094bb7a783e37ad1) example and the code I'm using to instantiate it is very similar to the `PagerActivity` in his example, while I changed the layout because I needed to use layout weights:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.example.myapp.PagerContainer
        android:id="@+id/pager_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.66"
        >
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </com.example.myapp.PagerContainer>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.34"
        android:id="@+id/current_selection_logo"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now my `ViewPager` works properly and looks like this (I omitted the bottom `ImageView`)

[image: current viewpager]

But I'd like to resize the unselected items, aiming to emphasize the centered item (selection), something like:

[image: wanted_viewpager]

or:

[image: wanted_viewpager_min]

I've found the accepted answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17437343/android-viewpager-with-center-item-bigger) question, but implementing that solution means that I'll make the selection bigger than its current dimensions (which already are the maximum possible).

So I was thinking to edit `instantiateItem` in the `PagerAdapter`  to set reduced width and height, and in `onPageSelected` use the approach shown in the question.

The problem is that I'm not sure about which kind of `LayoutParams` I should call and calling `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` in `instantiateItem` returns `0`.

Currently I'm using:

```
View v = container.getChildAt(position);
PagerContainer.LayoutParams params = (PagerContainer.LayoutParams)v.getLayoutParams();
```

but it sometimes works and sometimes throws a NPE.

Is my approach correct or should I proceed in another way?
In both cases, what should I change to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use a [PageTransform](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.PageTransformer.html) for this purpose. The callback you have to implement receives two parameters. The former is the View object, the latter is an `int`. When its value is zero, it means the view objects refers to the fully visible object to the center. -1 and -1, are the fully visible views to the left and right respectively. You can use this value to implement the transformation you want. Using ViewCompat, for instance, you can change the translationX, translationY and Scale values

Comment: If I understood correctly, PageTransform only affects the selected page and the two adjacent ones. What if I'm on a tablet or landscape mode and I can actually see more than three pages at once?

Comment: It's true when you use the normal implementation. With the PageContainer trick you'll get more. It's something that I discovered recently. What I can suggest you is to give it  try

Comment: I ended using a custom `PageTransformer`. Even if there's more than three pages visible the effect is shown properly!

Comment: I am doing exactly the same. But my i want to show 3 pages on screen at a time. I have done it successfully but the problem is that the scaled pages i.e (1st and 3nd) page's views aren't clickable.  Middle one isn't scaled and its views are clickable.

Comment: @ZeeshanShabbir, you will have to subclass ViewPager and handle the touch events. You might need to use one between View.getLocationOnScreen() and/or getLocationInWindow()

Comment: Thanks. @Blackbelt Kindly can you look into this?
 https://stackoverflow.com/q/45072946/5275639

Answer (score 7):

To achieve this result, I ended up using [PixPlicity's MultiViewPager](https://github.com/Pixplicity/MultiViewPager) and coding a simple `PageTransformer` as suggested by @Blackbelt:

```
private float mScale = 0.8f;
private class ScalePageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer{
    @Override
    public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
        if(position==0){
            ViewCompat.setScaleX(view, 1);
            ViewCompat.setScaleY(view, 1);
        }
        else{
            ViewCompat.setScaleX(view, mScale);
            ViewCompat.setScaleY(view, mScale);
        }
    }
}
```

The result is something like: 
[image: result]

Comment: You're welcome @KishanSoni, if you play a bit with the float `position` argument, you can even set different sizes according to the distance from the center item.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem like this. 
My solution is use [MultipleViewPager](https://github.com/Pixplicity/MultiViewPager) + [PagerTransformer](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#pagetransformer)

and it works fine.