# MultiViewPager+ZoomOutPageTransformer not working properly

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm trying to implement viewpager using [MultiViewPager](https://github.com/Pixplicity/MultiViewPager)
and Using google's zoomoutpageTransformer as effect, purpose is achieving something like this image :

[image]

but i can't display those two pages in right and left , each time i get a single page in middle of screen!
this is my view pager code :

```
        mViewPager.setPageMargin(
           -64);
    mAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity(), mClasses);
    mViewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new ZoomOutPageTransformer());
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

this is my viewpager in xml :

```
<ir.phzrobin.Utils.MultiViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    app:matchChildWidth="@+id/textview_class_title" >
</ir.phzrobin.Utils.MultiViewPager>
```

and this is my viewpager page layout :

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_class_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="fsafjabf"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="17sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_class_teacher"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview_class_title"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="fsafjabf"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="17sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button_options"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/overflow" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

what i have tried is 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27462253/viewpager-with-mutiple-visible-children-and-selected-bigger)
and also the multiviewpager developer's answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15006910/1724749)
can anybody please help me to achieve a goal?
thanks

this is view pager adapter:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

// ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
// DisplayImageOptions options;
// private ImageLoadingListener imageListener;

Context activity;
List<Classes> items;

public ViewPagerAdapter(Context activity, List<Classes> items) {

    this.activity = activity;
    this.items = items;
}

public void setItems(List<Classes> items) {
    this.items = items;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arg0 == arg1;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    final int pos = position;
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_viewpager, container, false);

    TextView mClassTitle = (TextView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.textview_class_title);
    mClassTitle.setText("عنوان درس: " + items.get(pos).getSubject());
    mClassTitle.setTypeface(AppFont.GetAppFont());
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_class_teacher))
            .setText("نام استاد: " + items.get(pos).getMasterName());
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_class_teacher))
            .setTypeface(AppFont.GetAppFont());
    RelativeLayout mLayout = (RelativeLayout) view
            .findViewById(R.id.rl_viewpager);
    mLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent _intent = new Intent(ContextVal.GetAppContext(),
                    ClassNotes.class);
            _intent.putExtra("CLASSID",
                    String.valueOf(items.get(pos).getID())); // set selected
                                                                // item id
                                                                // into
                                                                // intent
                                                                // activity
                                                                // to use in
                                                                // Classnotes
                                                                // Activity!
            activity.startActivity(_intent); // open notes activity

        }
    });
    ImageView mOverFlow = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.button_options);
    mOverFlow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(ContextVal.GetAppContext(), v);
            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.poupup_menu, popup.getMenu());
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    if(item.getIcon() != null)
                    {//edit item
                        Intent _ClassWindow = new Intent(ContextVal.GetAppContext(),
                                AddNewClass.class);
                        _ClassWindow.putExtra("CLASSID", String.valueOf(items.get(pos).getID()));
                        activity.startActivity(_ClassWindow);                       }
                    else{//delete item
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                ContextVal.GetAppContext());

                        builder.setTitle("حذف کلاس");
                        builder.setMessage("آیا مطمعن هستید که میخواهید این درس را حذف کنید ؟");

                        builder.setPositiveButton("بله", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // Do nothing but close the dialog
                                Log.e("onClick", "YES");
                                DatabaseHandler _db = new DatabaseHandler(ContextVal
                                        .GetAppContext());
                                _db.deleteClass(items.get(pos));
                                _db.deleteClassNotes(items.get(pos).getID());
                                ContextVal.mViewFragment.RefreshViewPager(); // Refresh Items !
                                                                            // and remove
                                                                            // deleted item from
                                                                            // user's eyes lol
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });

                        builder.setNegativeButton("خیر", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // Do nothing
                                Log.e("onClick", "NO");
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                        alert.show();                       }

                    return true;
                }
            });
            popup.show();
        }
    });

    container.addView(view, 0);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    container.removeView((View) object);
}
```

}

Comment: Please post your code for ViewPagerAdapter

Answer (score 1):

Look at this example fragment page layout from the MultiViewPager sample on GitHub:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/vg_cover"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_page"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/im_pixplicity"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_item"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:gravity="center" />

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

There is a `RelativeLayout` with width set to `match_parent` and an inner `FrameLayout` with an explicit width of 200dp.  What is in that inner `FrameLayout` ends up being the fragment page.

Your layout has `app:matchChildWidth="@+id/textview_class_title"` but that is not a `ViewGroup` like the inner `FrameLayout`.

You need to rewrite your fragment page layout so you have an inner `ViewGroup` with all your `TextView`s inside.

Also, do not explicitly call `setPageMargin()`, `MultiViewPager` sets the page margin internally based on all the measurements.

If you are still having problems getting this to work, I recommend starting with the sample application for MultiViewPager and modifying it until you get the layout results you are looking for.

Comment: its not working , i just set width to 400dp , also removed matchildwidth , and tried all possible forms , but still it not showing two classes on left and right

Comment: I just noticed the width of the MultiViewPager is wrap_content, and I think it should be match_parent.

Comment: no still the same! u asked me to upload the code , but the thing is ,   there is no extra class or layout to deal with! all is here

Answer (score 1):

I have multiple fragment in my activity, and I use `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` as PageAdapter and `MultiViewPager` as ViewPager.

These code below works fine with Google's `ZoomOutPageTransformer`:

Activity:

```
    <com.tencent.qest.ui.components.MultiViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    app:matchChildWidth="@+id/card_container"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pager_numbers"/>
```

Fragment:

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/card_container"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/img_banner_card"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:minHeight="64dp"
        android:src="@drawable/place_holder_1"

        android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:maxHeight="64dp" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="com.tencent.qest.ui.fragments.SimpleInfoCardFragment"
        android:padding="18dp"
        android:background="@color/accent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/img_banner_card"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/txt_card_normal"
            android:text="10.发放入职礼品"
            android:id="@+id/tv_Title"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/txt_card_normal"
            android:text="地点：4楼休闲厅"
            android:id="@+id/tv_SubTitle"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|left"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="4dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Tips:必须完成前9项后才可以领取入职礼品哦！"
            android:id="@+id/tv_Content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|left"
            style="@style/txt_card_normal" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just made it fine with this custom PageTransformer and MultiviewPager :

```
public class ScalePageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer{
    private static final float scaleMax = 0.8f;
    @Override
    public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
        if (position<=0){
            float scale = scaleMax + (1+position)*0.2f;
            ViewCompat.setScaleX(view, scale);
            ViewCompat.setScaleY(view, scale);
        } else {
            float scale = scaleMax + (1-position)*0.2f;
            ViewCompat.setScaleX(view, scale);
            ViewCompat.setScaleY(view, scale);
        }
    }
}
```