# Child views aren't clickable after scaling the rootview

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, android-animation, android-view

I am scaling `rootView` which is `LinearLayout` in `fragment` of `ViewPager` but child views aren't `clickable`.

This is the `rootView`

```
public class CarouselLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {
private float scale = CarouselPagerAdapter.BIG_SCALE;

public CarouselLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CarouselLinearLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public void setScaleBoth(float scale) {
    this.scale = scale;
    this.invalidate();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    // The main mechanism to display scale animation, you can customize it as your needs
    int w = this.getWidth();
    int h = this.getHeight();
    h = h - ((h / 2) / 2) / 2;
    canvas.scale(scale, scale, w / 2, h);// / 2
}

}
```

Here is relevant code where i am scaling the `rootview`.

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_fragment_dashboard, container, false);
        CarouselLinearLayout root = (CarouselLinearLayout) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.root_container);
        root.setScaleBoth(scale);
```

That's how it looks like.

[image]

Each circle is the page of `PagerView`. 1 - 2 - 3

Views in page 2 are clickable but views in page 1 and 3 aren't clickable. How can i fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should set that particular `Linear Layout` as `clickable` in your xml like below:

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Example:

```
                     <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical">
                    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This doesn't do anything. If i add this property then it makes pages doesn't respond to click events.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `ViewPager` with three pages and centre one should be scaled then use `ViewPager.PageTransformer` for this purpose.

Check this question: [ViewPager with mutiple visible children and selected bigger.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27462253/viewpager-with-mutiple-visible-children-and-selected-bigger?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Basically you override `transformPage(View view, float position)` and do your transformation for centre page.

For normal scaling always call `setScaleX()` and `setScaleY()` in `setScaleBoth()` instead of scaling canvas in `onDraw()`.

Comment: I tried doing this but this messed up the ui. I only see one circle on screen. I want to show 3 circles and middle one should be bigger than left and right and carouselling effect as well.